# Crawling Twitter with Java twitter4j and building graph of relationships

Tags: java

I am new to crawling social networks. Nevertheless, I need to write **Twitter** crawler that basically goes through **Twitter** and builds **dependency** **graph** between *Users* (with respect to relations like for example **follows**, **mentions**) and *Tweets*. I need to do it in **Java**. I know that there is **twitter4j** which basically can do much stuff with **Twitter**. The problem is that **twitter4j** is huge and I am somehow lost in getting what I need in my task from it. I know also that there is somehow limited **search** API and **streaming** API. Which one should I use when I want to get as much data from **Twitter** as possible ? So I would be greatful if anybody give me some directions how to get this data from **Twitter** (apart from parsing tons of **JSON** files if possible...). Any newbie guides much appreciated (what subset of **twitter4j** classes should I use, some tutorials if available, maybe some example code to get some data etc).

PS: Is it necessary to use **OAuth** to have full capabilities in obtaining data from **Twitter** ?